# jquery: get selected checkboxes, put in array, delimit the array and output to dynamic html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a web button that is generated dynamically depending on which checkboxes a user selects, without needing to reload the page. I guess jQuery is the way to do this but I am a complete noob with jQuery/JavaScript (trying to learn on the fly, which isn't easy).

Ultimately, I think it s/b a 2-step process: (1) as the user checks checkboxes, store them in an array and delimit them, and (2) output html to create a button that dynamically uses the delimited array values.

**HTML form:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catChoices[]" value="80s" />80s<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="catChoices[]" value="90s" />90s<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="catChoices[]" value="00s" />00s<br />
```

Being a jQuery/JS novice, I've only come up with this to do step 1 mentioned above. I don't know if this is on the right track or completely off:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input").click(function() {
       var checkValues = $('input[name=catChoices]:checked').map(function() {
         return $(this).val();
       }).get();
       str = checkValues.join(',');
     });
  });
```

I also don't know how to incorporate step 2 (get the button to be created dynamically with jQuery). The solutions I've googled show how to pass the values to html/PHP, which requires a page refresh, but I want the button to update on-the-fly as the user checks/unchecks checkboxes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A general suggestion: Better use `jQuery(function($){})` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Another general suggestion: Instead of `get()` use `toArray()` when you use .map, as it shows the intent much better

Comment: Also, read on .serialize() since what you are doing seems very wrong on the code design level

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use such a non-standard (for the web) format?

Have you thought about doing this:

```
var data = $('input[name="catChoices[]"]').serialize();
```

This is smart enough to only include checked checkboxes.

Granted, you can always convert it to a comma-separated list by doing

```
data = data.replace(/&/g, ',').replace(/catChoices%5B%5D=/g, '')
```

Creating a button is as simple as:

```
$('<button>', { val: data })
or
$('<input>',  { type: 'submit', val: data })

a different api is preferred by some:
$('<input type="submit">').val(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Name of the input box is catChoices[] and it should be in quotes.

```
 $("input").click(function() {
   var checkValues = $('input[name="catChoices[]"]:checked').map(function() {
     return $(this).val();
   }).get();
   str = checkValues.join(',');
       alert(str );
 });
```

Comment: He wants to create a button. Something like `$('#formid').append($('<input>').val(str));`